# Qt Display Japanese Character as Square

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, cjk

I have a simple program, in which I need to display japanese characters. It has a bit strange behaviour( in my opinion ), sometimes it displays character as it is, sometimes it displays it like square.

Normal/correct display

[image]

Issue observed time

[image]

My code as follows

**japanesedisplay.cpp**

```
#include "japanesedisplay.h"
#include "ui_japanesedisplay.h"

JapaneseDisplay::JapaneseDisplay(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::JapaneseDisplay)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->label->setText("こんにちは");
}

JapaneseDisplay::~JapaneseDisplay()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "japanesedisplay.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    JapaneseDisplay w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

My Qt version : 5.3.2

My Platform : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When it generates strange behavior, are you executing it in the machine? How often does that problem happen? Have you modified something before it happens?

Comment: Looks like a missing font and/or a font missing characters.

Comment: „Sometimes“ is really hard to debug, you have to identify the common aspects when it works or not. Regarding this post https://wiki.qt.io/Strings_and_encodings_in_Qt you should encapsulated the string with tr() to ensure an utf -8 encoding.

Comment: Always wrap string literals in the [QStringLiteral](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QStringLiteral) marco, especially if they contain non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Also using non asci

Comment: @eyllanesc My working platform is PC, Except this issue all other qt features are works fine. I tried **QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont** with a japanese supporting font. and also tried **tr()**. But still sometimes issue exist.

Comment: こんにちは Mr Salim Kumar:), Is this issue surely happens only sometimes?.. As an information, if you have japanese fonts copied  issue may be fixed. You can copy the fonts from /usr/share/fonts or usr/lib/fonts   to Qt installed path  ../5.3.2/lib/fonts. Make sure japanese font is available on the path and make sure you set QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));

Comment: @Ashif Yes, this issue only happens sometimes.  i tried `id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/Boku2-Bold.otf");` and `QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-‌​8"));`, but issue stiil exist.